# Post a message to LinkedIn with Scribe in not working in Android

Tags: java, android, oauth, linkedin-api, scribe

Below is the code to send a post message. On my screen i have an EditText section to allow the user to enter text and when they hit post the sendMessage function is called. I keep getting this in the response. I have also tried URLEncode.encode(payload, "UTF-8") to get an encoded string to add to the body and that did not work. Any insight would be helpful.

```
04-19 18:24:50.570: D/response(693): <error>
04-19 18:24:50.570: D/response(693):   <status>400</status>
04-19 18:24:50.570: D/response(693):   <timestamp>1334859891007</timestamp>
04-19 18:24:50.570: D/response(693):   <request-id>WJPI8VXQME</request-id>
04-19 18:24:50.570: D/response(693):   <error-code>0</error-code>
04-19 18:24:50.570: D/response(693):   <message>Couldn't parse share document: error: Unexpected end of file after null</message>
04-19 18:24:50.570: D/response(693): </error>
```

Here is the code:

```
private static final String SendMessage = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares";

public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    //Get works just fine
    //OAuthRequest req = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,last-name)");
    //service.signRequest(accessToken, req);
    //Response res = req.send();
    //Log.e("get", res.getBody());

    OAuthRequest post = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, SendMessage);

    //Have also  tried adding <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" to the beginning of the payload string        
    String payload = "<share>" +
                        "<comment>testing</comment>" +
                        "<visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility>" +
                     "</share>";

    post.addBodyParameter("body", payload);
    post.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");

    service.signRequest(accessToken, post);
    try
    {
        Response response = post.send();
        Log.d("response",response.getBody());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LinkedInActivity.this.finish();
}
```

and my service is being defined as:

```
service = new ServiceBuilder()
                .provider(LinkedInApi.class)
                .apiKey(API_KEY)
                .apiSecret(API_SEC)
                .callback(CALLBACK)
                .debug()
                .build();

final Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
final String authURL = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
```

I use a webview to catch the callback to save the verifier/token.  Example is below:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if(url.startsWith("oauth")){
                webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
                Verifier v = new Verifier(verifier);

                //save token
                accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, v);

                if(uri.getHost().equals("linkedIn")){
                    editText.setText(appState.socialMediaMessage);
                    //place the cursor at the end of the predefined text
                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());

                    textLimit = textLimit - editText.length();
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(textLimit));

                }

                return true;
            }

            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });

    //send user to authorization page
    webView.loadUrl(authURL);
```

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
post.addPayload(payload);
```

instead of:

```
post.addBodyParameter("body", payload);
```