# LinkedIn integration in my Android app

Tags: android

I'm looking for a working sample to integrate LinkedIn in my Android app.

I already have googled and tried some sample available but none of them worked.

Comment: SocialAuth Android is an Android version of popular SocialAuth Java library. Now you do not need to integrate multiple SDKs if you want to integrate your application with multiple social networks. You just need to add few lines of code after integrating the SocialAuth Android library in your app. Go to this [socialauth-android](https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android/wiki/Getting-Started). One of the best approach to integrate all social media

Answer (score 0):

**LinkedIn Integration:**
    There is no official linkedIn androidSDK like facebook. But they suggest some third party libraries [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/libraries-and-tools).  Scribe is the only linkedIn tested lib. So going ahead with it.[Tutorial](http://www.sourcetricks.com/2012/07/android-linkedin-oauth-implementation.html).

Dont forget to creat an app on linkedin and get your apiKey and apiSecret.

Create a webview and use this code in your asyncTask:

```
/**
 * Linked in Authorization. 
 * **/
public class LinkedInAuthTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    // OAuthComponents
    OAuthService service;
    final static String CALLBACK = "oauth://linkedin";
    Token requestToken;

    CustomWebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mWebView = (CustomWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        // OAuthServiceObject
        service = new ServiceBuilder()
                     .provider(LinkedInApi.class)
                     .apiKey("YourapiKey")
                     .apiSecret("yourApiSecret")
                     .callback(CALLBACK)
                     .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Temporary URL
        String authURL = "http://api.linkedin.com/";

        try {
            requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
            authURL = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
        } catch (OAuthException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return authURL;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String authURL) {
        super.onPostExecute(authURL);
        log('d', TAG, "Oauth URL: " + authURL);
        toast(authURL);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                log('d', TAG, "Oauth URL: " + url);
                if (url.startsWith("oauth")) {
                    mWebView.setVisibility(WebView.GONE);

                    final String url1 = url;
                    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url1);

                            String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
                            Verifier v = new Verifier(verifier);

                            Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(
                                    requestToken, v);
                                    Log.i("Your LinkedInToken", accessToken.getToken());
                                    Log.i("Your LinkedInSecret", accessToken.getSecret());

                            finish();
                        }
                    };
                    t1.start();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        mWebView.loadUrl(authURL);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for how LinkedIn aunthentication done now how can I share a message from my app to LinkedIn's wall?

Comment: You should first get the linked in token. You have to make a different api call with that token to do that.

Comment: I'm done with having the token, now how do i post my message over LinkedIn?

Comment: Check this [so post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10246770/2219600) , and dont forget to upvoat if it helped u.